# how to select shadow-root elements

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Using polymer and I have problem in selecting an element by it's tag name.

```
<canvas id="chart" width="150" height="150"></canvas>

.

..

...

_drawChart(price, time) { var ctx = this.$.canvas.getContext('2d'); //error happened here

.

..

...

}
```

now `this.$.canvas.getContext('2d');` returns an error in the console, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined.`

I went to select the element manually from the console by getElementById it returned null, noting that canvas resides in shadow-root tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.$.chart.getContext('2d');` instead `this.$.canvas.getContext('2d');`

Comment: Thats it, can you give me a keywords to read more about how polymer accesses dom nodes

Comment: Automatic node finding: Polymer automatically builds a map of statically created instance nodes in its local DOM, to provide convenient access to frequently used nodes without the need to query for them manually. Any node specified in the element's template with an id is stored on the this.$ hash by id. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom

Answer (score 0):

`this.shadowRoot.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');` also works.
A bit longer but more native.